# Do google cloud functions pip install every time one is invoked or just when you deploy it?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

Do google cloud functions pip install every time one is invoked or just when you deploy it?

Answer (score 1):

`pip install` is only done during deployment of the function. Basically, the [deployment](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying#deployment) process would be:

1. Upload the function's source code to GCS.
2. Build container image from the src in Cloud Build, in which one of the step is installing packages (`pip install`).
3. Cloud Functions uses the container image to execute the function.